# Is it possible to use dynamic type sizes with a custom font in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, user-interface, fonts, swiftui

I'm playing around with SwiftUI, and want to use a custom UI font for my project. However, I don't want to lose the dynamic type resizing that comes with the built-in font classes (e.g. Large Title).

Apple does provide a custom font modifier for `Text`:

```swift
Text("Hello, world!")
    .font(.custom("Papyrus", size: 17))
```

However, this fixes the size to 17pt. When you run this on a device or in the Simulator and open the Accessibility Inspector to adjust the OS-level font size, the `Text` element does not update.

The `size:` parameter is not optional, so you must pass in something. And unfortunately, you can't get the `size` of an existing font (even a custom one), because `Font` does not have a `size` parameter.

It seems to be a common pattern in the rest of SwiftUI that parameters can either be optional, or you can pass in `nil` to explicitly disable certain behavior. I would expect the `size:` parameter on `.custom()` to be optional, and internally either use the size from a previous `Font` modifier, or to use the default size set by `Text`.

Alternately, the static methods that define system styles (e.g. `.largeTitle`) could accept an argument that provides a custom font name: `.largeTitle("Papyrus")`

Does anyone have a workaround?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I stumbled upon a nice way to achieve this also via `ViewModifier`. I borrowed the base modifier from [this Hacking With Swift's article](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-dynamic-type-with-a-custom-font) on Dynamic Type and Custom Fonts. Here's the result:

```
import SwiftUI

@available(iOS 13, macCatalyst 13, tvOS 13, watchOS 6, *)
struct CustomFont: ViewModifier {
    @Environment(\.sizeCategory) var sizeCategory

    var name: String
    var style: UIFont.TextStyle
    var weight: Font.Weight = .regular

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        return content.font(Font.custom(
            name,
            size: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: style).pointSize)
            .weight(weight))
    }
}

@available(iOS 13, macCatalyst 13, tvOS 13, watchOS 6, *)
extension View {
    func customFont(
        name: String,
        style: UIFont.TextStyle,
        weight: Font.Weight = .regular) -> some View {
        return self.modifier(CustomFont(name: name, style: style, weight: weight))
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
Text("Hello World!")
    .customFont(name: "Georgia", style: .headline, weight: .bold)
```

This way you can stick to bundled Text Styles without needing to provide sizes explicitly. Should you want to do so, the `font` modifier already allow us to, and the scaling could be handled through one of the alternative approaches given to this question.

Also, please note that because the styling is applied within a `ViewModifier` conformant `struct`, which in turn responds to changes to the environment's `sizeCategory`, the views will reflect changes to the accessibility settings right upon switching back to your app; so there's no need to restart it.

Comment: This is fantastic—thanks! I much prefer this to manually specifying the scales of each style. 

Comment: This is fantastic and I am using it in my App right now. Minor annoyance: it doesn't seem work for previews in the canvas with the size class environment modifier.

Answer (score 21):

The way I would do it, is by creating a custom modifier that can be bound to the changes of the environment's size category:

Whenever you need to use Papyrus, you would use it like this:

```swift
Text("Hello World!").modifier(Papyrus())
```

or like this:

```swift
Text("Hello World!").modifier(Papyrus(.caption))
Text("Hello World!").modifier(Papyrus(.footnote))
Text("Hello World!").modifier(Papyrus(.subheadline))
Text("Hello World!").modifier(Papyrus(.callout))
Text("Hello World!").modifier(Papyrus())
Text("Hello World!").modifier(Papyrus(.body))
Text("Hello World!").modifier(Papyrus(.headline))
Text("Hello World!").modifier(Papyrus(.title))
Text("Hello World!").modifier(Papyrus(.largeTitle))
```

Your text will now dynamically change without further work. This is the same code, reacting to different text size preference:

[image]

And your Papyrus() implementation will look something like this. You'll need to figure out the right values for each category, this is just an example:

```swift
struct Papyrus: ViewModifier {
    @Environment(\.sizeCategory) var sizeCategory
    var textStyle: Font.TextStyle

    init(_ textStyle: Font.TextStyle = .body) {
        self.textStyle = textStyle
    }

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.font(getFont())
    }

    func getFont() -> Font {
        switch(sizeCategory) {
        case .extraSmall:
            return Font.custom("Papyrus", size: 16 * getStyleFactor())
        case .small:
            return Font.custom("Papyrus", size: 21 * getStyleFactor())
        case .medium:
            return Font.custom("Papyrus", size: 24 * getStyleFactor())
        case .large:
            return Font.custom("Papyrus", size: 28 * getStyleFactor())
        case .extraLarge:
            return Font.custom("Papyrus", size: 32 * getStyleFactor())
        case .extraExtraLarge:
            return Font.custom("Papyrus", size: 36 * getStyleFactor())
        case .extraExtraExtraLarge:
            return Font.custom("Papyrus", size: 40 * getStyleFactor())
        case .accessibilityMedium:
            return Font.custom("Papyrus", size: 48 * getStyleFactor())
        case .accessibilityLarge:
            return Font.custom("Papyrus", size: 52 * getStyleFactor())
        case .accessibilityExtraLarge:
            return Font.custom("Papyrus", size: 60 * getStyleFactor())
        case .accessibilityExtraExtraLarge:
            return Font.custom("Papyrus", size: 66 * getStyleFactor())
        case .accessibilityExtraExtraExtraLarge:
            return Font.custom("Papyrus", size: 72 * getStyleFactor())
        @unknown default:
            return Font.custom("Papyrus", size: 36 * getStyleFactor())
        }
    }

    func getStyleFactor() -> CGFloat {
        switch textStyle {
        case .caption:
            return 0.6
        case .footnote:
            return 0.7
        case .subheadline:
            return 0.8
        case .callout:
            return 0.9
        case .body:
            return 1.0
        case .headline:
            return 1.2
        case .title:
            return 1.5
        case .largeTitle:
            return 2.0
        @unknown default:
            return 1.0
        }
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**

I modified the implementation to accept a text style as parameter.

Comment: I modified the implementation to accept a text style as parameter.

Comment: This is a great workaround—nice work!  I hope we get a better first-party solution though, because it feels a little hacky to hard code all those point sizes as magic numbers. But this is absolutely what I will do in the short term. Thanks! 

Comment: Glad to help. The nice thing of this approach is that later, if another method becomes available, you can easily rewrite the modifier Papyrus and you will not need to change your code.

Comment: For anyone using this approach, you might want to reference [the official point sizes](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/typography/) for each size class in Apple's Human Interface Guidelines 

Comment: You can use UIFontMetrics to avoid switching on the sizeCategory. You need to write a converter from Font.TextStyle to UIFont.TextStyle, but this is pretty trivial.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to keep a SwiftUI-like style, you can extend **`Font`** for UIKit-compatible platforms:

```
import SwiftUI

extension Font {

    #if canImport(UIKit)

    static var myHeadline = Font.custom(
        "Your-Font-Name",
        size: UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: .headline).scaledValue(for: 17)
    )

    #endif
}
```

Then, to use it:

```
Text("Hello World!")
    .font(.myHeadline)
```

Note that your custom fonts *won't update unless you restart the application*. This means that the canvas preview won't work either this way.

I'll be investigating this topic further as soon as I find time for it.

(Also, this should be a native feature. If there's `Font.system(_ style: Font.TextStyle, design: Font.Design = .default)`, there should be `Font.custom(_ name: String, style: Font.TextStyle)` too. See FB6523689 in Feedback.)

Comment: Yeah, good point, this is a nice workaround for now. I've been trying to keep my new views 100% SwiftUI, but for certain things it may make sense to dip into UIKit for the time being. I also filed feedback on this (FB6203782), proposing to move `fontStyle` into a modifier, along with `fontFamily`, so you could do this:

`Text("Hello, world!").fontStyle(.title).fontFamily("Avenir")`