# Listen for Environment Changes

Tags: swift, swiftui

How do I detect environment changes in SwiftUI?
For example, I store the current colour scheme as

```
@Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme: ColorScheme
```

And I display an `ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton` based on the environment value:

```
fileprivate struct AppleSignInView : UIViewRepresentable {

    var colorScheme: ColorScheme

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton {
        switch colorScheme {
        case .light:
            return ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton(type: .continue, style: .black)

        case .dark:
            return ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton(type: .continue, style: .white)

        @unknown default:
            return ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton(type: .continue, style: .black)
        }
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton, context: Context) { }
}
```

And In my `body` property I instantiate the struct:

```
var body: some View {
    AppleSignInView(colorScheme: colorScheme)
}
```

This works fine, but the new colour scheme isn't propagated when I change the colour scheme from the Xcode.

How do I listen to this environment variable change?

Comment: doing bata-binding probably helps....

Answer (score 10):

Here is how I do it: the trick is to add the `.id(self.colorScheme)` line. This forces SwiftUI to redraw this button every time the colorScheme changes.

```swift
SignInWithAppleButton(style: self.colorScheme == .light ? .black : .white)
  .frame(width: 280, height: 60)
  .onTapGesture(perform: self.showAppleLogin)
  .id(self.colorScheme)
```

This saves you from returning 2 versions of the button in an if/else statement, like in kontiki's answer.

And my button, for good measure:

```swift
struct SignInWithAppleButton: UIViewRepresentable {
  var style: ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton.Style

  func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton {
    return ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton(type: .default, style: style)
  }

  func updateUIView(_ uiView: ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton, context: Context) {}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I recently answer a similar question, the OP was looking for a way of having custom fonts reacting to environment changes of the .sizeCategory.

Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56730649/7786555

---

### UPDATE

Here's an implementation that works. Notice that **AppleSignInView** is put inside an if statement. This is to force SwiftUI recreate your **UIViewRepresantable**. Ideally you would just pass the colorScheme, but in that case you need to change the **ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton.style** in **updateUIView()**. However, .style is not modifiable. To work around it, you use the if statement to force a recreation of the SignIn button.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import AuthenticationServices

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme: ColorScheme

    var body: some View {

        Group {
            if colorScheme == .light {
                AppleSignInView(colorScheme: .light).frame(width: 200, height: 50)
            } else {
                AppleSignInView(colorScheme: .dark).frame(width: 200, height: 50)
            }
        }
    }
}

fileprivate struct AppleSignInView : UIViewRepresentable {
    var colorScheme: ColorScheme

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton {
        switch colorScheme {
        case .light:
            return ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton(type: .continue, style: .black)

        case .dark:
            return ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton(type: .continue, style: .white)

        @unknown default:
            return ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton(type: .continue, style: .black)
        }
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton, context: Context) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Also note that there seem to be many bugs with the dark/light mode in the current beta 2.

Comment: Updated my answer to include a working solution. Tested on simulator and changed color scheme from the Settings app.