# Signin With Apple Button errors on \.colorScheme

Tags: swiftui, apple-sign-in

[image]
I'm trying to figure out what I am missing and it is driving me nuts.  I am following the Google Firestore To-Do tutorial and this code works on the "MakeItSo" git repository. complements to this link. Sign-in with apple added... Auth on firebase added... podfiles are good.
[Listen for Environment Changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56850908/listen-for-environment-changes)

Comment: Work fine here, Xcode 11.4. Check if there is no names conflict in your project.

Comment: HAHA! sometimes I'm holding my keys and looking for them... that was exactly what happened... Had another struct ColorScheme: View { ...